# Register a route change in React-router 1.0

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

Don't you know how can I register a route change in React-router 1.0? I have tried few classic react event listeners like onChange and it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want? Get notified when App route has been changed?

Comment: @just-boris I'm using socket.io and I want to join leave rooms. Yeah I want to have notification when in changes.

Comment: Ok, then that is okay to use onEnter/onLeave hooks on your root Route. Also, if you have Redux, you can try to use solution from the my anwser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [onEnter/onLeave](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/RouteConfiguration.md#enter-and-leave-hooks) hooks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Redux in your project and use [redux-router](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-router) or [redux-simple-router](https://github.com/rackt/redux-simple-router), you can add a middleware to capture their route change actions.

This is how it can be for redux-simple-router:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {syncReduxAndRouter, routeReducer, UPDATE_PATH} from 'redux-simple-router';

function routeListenerMiddleware({ dispatch, getState }) {
    return next => action => {
        if(action.type === UPDATE_PATH) {
             // deal with path update here.
        }
        next(action);
    }
}

const createRouteAwareStore = applyMiddleware(routeListenerMiddleware)(createStore)
```

Then you have the store, which intercepts route changes.